# SQLAlchemy load_only and defer

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have tried using the SQLAlchemy methods load_only and defer to send only certain columns from the database, but I can't seem to get them to work.

Here is the code I am using:

```
query = db.session.query(Vendor).options(defer('ownerName', 'boxSize', 'boxes', 'lastPickUp', 'zone', 'code'))
return response( query )
```

*response is a custom jsonify method I wrote because of the specific needs of my application.

I'm expecting the response:

> {
>
> "Response": [
>
> ```
> {
>
>   "address": "10th and SW Alder St",
>
>   "city": "Portland, OR",
>
>   "id": 1, 
>
>   "keywords": "Tacos, Mexican",
>
>   "latitude": 45.5206464, 
>
>   "longitude": -122.68157559999997, 
>
>   "name": "Taco Ted",
>
>   "phone": null, 
>
>   "website": null,
>
> },
> ```
>
> ...

But instead I'm getting:

> {
>
> "Response": [
>
> ```
> {
>
>   "address": "10th and SW Alder St", 
>
>   "boxSize": null, 
>
>   "boxes": 10, 
>
>   "city": "Portland, OR", 
>
>   "id": 1, 
>
>   "keywords": "Tacos, Mexican", 
>
>   "lastPickUp": "01/12/2014", 
>
>   "latitude": 45.5206464, 
>
>   "longitude": -122.68157559999997, 
>
>   "name": "Taco Ted", 
>
>   "ownerName": null, 
>
>   "phone": null, 
>
>   "website": null, 
>
>   "zone": 1
>
> },
> ```
>
> ...

Which means my defer is being ignored. I have tried using load_only to solve this problem as well but both of them seem to make no difference. What am I missing here?

(If it makes any difference I'm using a sqlite database for development.)

Comment: I guess that it is your `response` who is *responsible* for this. It probably iterates over all columns/fields of the model(s) it wraps, and this forces `sqlachemy` to issue additional `SQL` statements to load the `deferred` columns. So you are actually even making the application less efficient. Please take a look into your `response` in order to fix this.

Comment: Your right my response is iterating over the query. Is their a property to check if a column is deferred?

Comment: Why don't you just add a deferred column list as a parameter to the `response` function, so that it would not iterate over them...

Comment: That is a solution. I'd rather use the standard way of using defer and then having response respect that for standard and readability reasons.

Comment: After some googling and research, it seems much easier to just add the defer to my response method. (In fact I already got that working.) Thanks for the point in the right direction van.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that's not the correct usage of `deferred()` and the use case you have here is why `load_only()` was added.  each call to `deferred()` only does one attribute at a time; the fact that it accepts many strings has to do with "paths" in the query, which is not what you're dealing with here.

load_only() will prevent attributes that are not named from being loaded in the initial query:

```
load_only('ownerName', 'boxSize', 'boxes', 'lastPickUp', 'zone', 'code')
```

however, if your jsonify method still calls upon those attributes, like `somevendor.boxSize`, it will emit the SQL at that point.  so it depends on how you are pulling the attributes as well.

Comment: ```load_only()``` does not prevent attributes from being loaded, it is the contrary, it only loads the attributes. For this case, I would then use ```load_only('id', 'address', 'city', 'keywords', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'name', 'phone', 'website')```

Comment: i amended the statement.   internally, it gets the list of all attributes and does "deferred()" for the ones that are not there :)